# What is the difference between ObjectInputStreamReader and InputStreamReader?

Tags: java, inputstream, objectinputstream

My teacher said that in file server program `ObjectInputStreamReader` is compulsory  to write. When I asked the reason then he  said me it is comfortable for file server program. I am thinking that it is not necessary reason. Why `InputStreamReader` or other alternatives can not be used? what is the advantage of `ObjectInputStreamReader` over `InputStreamReader`.

Here code for client/server:

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Socket s = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String data = "";
        try {
            s = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
            System.out.println("client is connectd");

            ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            String jai = (String) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("DATA from SERVER:" + jai);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Enter file name:");
        try {
            String fil = (String) sc.next();
            OutputStream pw = new FileOutputStream(fil + ".new");
            oos.writeObject(fil);
            data = (String) ois.readObject();
            pw.write(data.getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("Content of file:" + data);
    }
}
```

Can any one say what is actual reason ?

Comment: There's no such class as "ObjectInputStramReader". There's not even "ObjectInputStreamReader". Note that your sample code uses ObjectInputStream - there's no "Reader" part here. ObjectInputStream and InputStreamReader are entirely different... but you haven't told us what you're trying to *achieve*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean `ObjectInputStream` and `BufferedInputStream` (not readers).

`ObjectInputStream` wraps input stream and provides typed methods that allow reading data of certain type from the stream. For example `readDouble()`, `readObject()` etc.

`BufferedInputStream` does not provide additional API (comparing to regular `InputStream`). The only thing it does is buffering of data, i.e. it reads data chunk-by-chunk that is much more efficient way than reading byte-by-byte.

Comment: there is  any compulsion to read from file  i have to use ObjectInputStraemReader.

Answer (score 2):

An `InputStream` is an *abstract class* that can be used to define any type of input stream, including reading from file systems, URLs, sockets, etc.

You don't actually create an `InputStream`, as it doesn't mean anything by itself. Rather, you create a *type* of `InputStream` that defines how to read/write a particular type of data, such as the suggested `ObjectInputStream`. This class defines that the data being written is a Java `Object` (that implements `Serializable` or `Externalizable`). There are other `InputStreams` that are used for generic file data, images, audio, and a whole range of other types.

There is no such thing as an `ObjectInputStreamReader`, unless you write a class like this yourself that has the purpose of writing to an `ObjectInputStream`.

Refer to the [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) and [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) Java docs for more enlightenment